# Extract Relative Link by using Selenium with phantom JS driver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using **Selemium** with **Phantom JS** driver to load a HTML page and extract all the HREF links from it.
PhantomJS gives me absolute URLs after resolving them completely.

My requirement is to extract relative links as it is.

I am fetching hrefs by walking the DOM . But it gives me resolved URL. I want to get relative url as it is.

```
List<WebElement> list =  driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (WebElement element:list) {
    String link = element.getAttribute("href");`
}
```

For example:

```
  <a href="../index.html" ></a> with base url - http:docs.oracle.com/en/test.htm
```

Phantom JS gives me resolved link - http:docs.oracle.com/index.htm
My requirement get the relative link as below.
**Relative link : "../index.htm"**

Is there any way in Selenium + Phantom JS to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.
Neha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I have found that Selenium does not provide any direct option to retrieve relative links as it is. 
I have found a  workaround to get the relative link.
We can get outerHTML using

`String outerHTML = element.getAttribute("outerHTML");`

and then use DOMParser to parse ans extract the href from it.